# There is Proxy-object instead just index when change tab in materia-ui/Tabs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I try to use [material-ui tabs](https://material-ui.com/demos/tabs/)  => Fixed Tabs  => Full width tabs panel
I have function component OvertiemsReport with Tabs:

```
const TabContainer = ({children, dir}) => (
  <Typography component="div" dir={dir} style={{padding: 8 * 3}}>
    {children}
  </Typography>
);

const OvertimesReport = ({preview = false, tabValue, handleChange, classes}) => (
  <div className={classes.workarea}>
    <Card>
      <CardContent className="overtimes">
        <Typography variant="display2">Отчет о переработках</Typography>
        <Grid container spacing={24} className={classes.gridContainer}>
          <Grid item>
            {preview}
            <div className={classes.root}>
              <AppBar position="static" color="default">
                <Tabs
                  value={tabValue}
                  onChange={handleChange}
                  indicatorColor="primary"
                  textColor="secondary"
                  fullWidth
                >
                  <Tab label="Item One"/>
                  <Tab label="Item Two"/>
                </Tabs>
              </AppBar>
            </div>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
      </CardContent>
    </Card>
  </div>
);
```

and I have external handeChange function
handleChange: value => dispatch(actions.handleChangeTab(value)),

and value stored in redux.

So, after I click to change tab, in input of handeChange I recieve Proxy-object instead just a number of chose tab

Received object in handleChange method like this: 
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function given to the `onChange` prop of the `Tabs` component is called with the `event` and `value` as arguments.

It will work if you change your event handler to this:

```
handleChange: (event, value) => dispatch(actions.handleChangeTab(value)),
```